# Interspersing a text with numbered propositions

Tags: lists, environments

I wanted to intersperse a text with numbered propositions, so I
defined a list that would not reset its counter.

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{enumitem}

    \newlist{propositions}{enumerate}{1}%
    \setlist[propositions]{
      label=(\arabic*),
      resume,
    }

    \begin{document}

    \begin{propositions}
      \item foo
    \end{propositions}

    \begin{propositions}
      \item bar
    \end{propositions}
```

This works as expected, but, since I would usually give one
proposition at a time, the `\item` seemed redundant, so I
wrapped the environment in a new environment that included the
`\item`.

```
    \newenvironment{proposition}{\begin{propositions}\item}{\end{propositions}}


    \begin{proposition}
      baz
    \end{proposition}

    \begin{proposition}
      boo
    \end{proposition}

    \end{document}
```

But now something undesirable happens, for the numbers produced
are 1, 2, 3, 3.  Presumably the wrapping localizes the counter,
so that it doesn't survive until the next proposition-environment?
How do I remedy this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newlist{propositions}{enumerate}{1}%
\setlist[propositions]{
  label=(\arabic*),
  resume,
}
\newenvironment{proposition}
  {\propositions\item}
  {\endpropositions}

\begin{document}

\begin{proposition}
foo
\end{proposition}

\begin{proposition}
bar
\end{proposition}

\end{document}
```

[image]

However, you should consider a different approach.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheoremstyle{propositions}
  {\topsep}     % ABOVESPACE
  {\topsep}     % BELOWSPACE
  {\itshape}    % BODYFONT
  {0pt}         % INDENT 
  {\normalfont} % HEADFONT
  {}            % HEADPUNCT
  {5pt plus 1pt minus 1pt} % HEADSPACE
  {(\thmnumber{#2})}       % CUSTOM-HEAD-SPEC

\theoremstyle{propositions}
\newtheorem{proposition}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{proposition}
foo
\end{proposition}

\begin{proposition}
bar
\end{proposition}

\end{document}
```

Change `\itshape` into `\normalfont` if you prefer upright type for the body.

You can also support “named propositions”

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheoremstyle{propositions}
  {\topsep}     % ABOVESPACE
  {\topsep}     % BELOWSPACE
  {\itshape}    % BODYFONT
  {0pt}         % INDENT 
  {\normalfont} % HEADFONT
  {}            % HEADPUNCT
  {5pt plus 1pt minus 1pt} % HEADSPACE
  {(\thmnumber{#2})}       % CUSTOM-HEAD-SPEC

\theoremstyle{propositions}
\newtheorem{proposition}{}

\newenvironment{proposition*}[1]
 {\addtocounter{proposition}{-1}\renewcommand{\theproposition}{#1}\proposition}
 {\endproposition}

\begin{document}

References: \ref{prop:foo}, \ref{prop:bar}, \ref{prop:K}, \ref{prop:check}.

\begin{proposition}\label{prop:foo}
foo
\end{proposition}

\begin{proposition}\label{prop:bar}
bar
\end{proposition}

\begin{proposition*}{K}\label{prop:K}
K is this one
\end{proposition*}

\begin{proposition}\label{prop:check}
check
\end{proposition}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you also want `hyperref` to cooperate, you have to modify the previous code slightly.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newtheoremstyle{propositions}
  {\topsep}     % ABOVESPACE
  {\topsep}     % BELOWSPACE
  {\itshape}    % BODYFONT
  {0pt}         % INDENT 
  {\normalfont} % HEADFONT
  {}            % HEADPUNCT
  {5pt plus 1pt minus 1pt} % HEADSPACE
  {(\thmnumber{#2})}       % CUSTOM-HEAD-SPEC

\theoremstyle{propositions}
\newtheorem{proposition}{}

\newenvironment{proposition*}[1]
 {%
  \addtocounter{proposition}{-1}%
  \renewcommand{\theproposition}{#1}%
  \renewcommand{\theHproposition}{#1}%
  \proposition
 }
 {\endproposition}

\begin{document}

References: \ref{prop:foo}, \ref{prop:bar}, \ref{prop:K}, \ref{prop:check}.

\begin{proposition}\label{prop:foo}
foo
\end{proposition}

\begin{proposition}\label{prop:bar}
bar
\end{proposition}

\begin{proposition*}{K}\label{prop:K}
K is this one
\end{proposition*}

\begin{proposition}\label{prop:check}
check
\end{proposition}

\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks!  does your preferred approach support using a custom tag for certain propositions?

Comment: @Probert Not sure what you mean.

Comment: i mean, if i want to call a certain proposition (K) instead of the current number, can i do that?  \tag doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @Probert I added a possible solution